# How can I know the Bitcoin Transfer Transactions on Bisq?

Tags: multi-signature, bisq

I am trying to get some blocks from [Bisq](https://bisq.markets/blocks).
I used their API to get the [blocks](https://bisq.markets/docs/api/rest#get-blocks). Then I discovered that blocks are missing some inputs, so I used their API again to get [these transactions](https://bisq.markets/docs/api/rest#get-transaction).

But, I discovered that these transactions contain just the BSQ transfer, and the fee payment transactions (in BTC). I was not able to see the transactions related to the Bitcoin Transfer. How can I get the Bitcoin Transfer Transactions from Bisq block.

To give an example:
Here is a Bisq transaction (012ffb03e13a50902b8cc898dbad984cb6f4055cad97e33f2d1a627facf3fabf).
I used [Bisq API](https://bisq.markets/api/tx/012ffb03e13a50902b8cc898dbad984cb6f4055cad97e33f2d1a627facf3fabf) to get it. The height of this transaction is 713592, When I looked for this transaction of Bisq ([here](https://bisq.markets/block/000000000000000000071ab7b5dc11d94479f8ae205a0600df3219331a85e63f)) I found that it has 0 transactions.
This is a MultiSig transaction, but I do not have any transaction like that on Bisq blocks, even when I get the blocks or transactions by Bisq API.

Is there a way I can get the Bitcoin Transfer Transactions (MultiSig) from Bisq blocks, or another way to get them?

Comment: Since other blockchain explorers show [transactions in that block](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/block/713592) - you should probably ask customer support at Bisq why you get the results you do.